# stratified sampling R - more directions needed

Tags: r, statistics, sampling

To reduce the dataset, I have been advised to use "stratified sampling".

Because I'm very new to the R programming, current articles on Stack aren't easy to follow, there is very little explanation.

I have a data set of over 60000 obs. and 24 variables. Out of all variables, 21 are quantitative (numbers).

How do I get sample data out of that? Also
- Where do I specify the dataset name
- do I need to name the new "reduced" dataset, so I could include it for the further analysis?

---

ADDED CODE (this is what I used for sampling):

```
# Sample a percentage of values from each stratum (10% in this case)
DB.quant.sample = lapply(split(DB.quant, DB.quant$group_size), function(DB.quant) {
  DB.quant[sample(1:nrow(DB.quant), ceiling(nrow(DB.quant) * 0.1)), ]
})

Browse[1]>DB.quant[sample(1:nrow(DB.quant), 6000), ]

#DB.quant is the dataset and group_size is one of the variable. I'm not sure which variable should I use?
```

---

I'm having problem with illustrating graphically and intuitively how a cluster algorithm works
I started:

```
DB <- na.omit(DB)
DB.quant <- DB[c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)]
```

And then:

```
d <- dist(DB.quant.sample) # but im getting an error: 
Error in dist(DB.quant.sample, method = "euclidean") : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

---

Example image of my DataSet:
[first few rows of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzQNC.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to sample, but here's a simple example using the built-in `iris` data frame. Below are two ways to do it. One using Base R and the other using the `dplyr` package.

#### Base R

1. `split` the data frame into three separate smaller data frames, one for each `Species`.
2. Randomly `sample` 5 rows per `Species`.

   ```
   # Sample 5 rows from each stratum
   df.sample = lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(df) {
     df[sample(1:nrow(df), 5), ]
   })

   # Sample a percentage of values from each stratum (10% in this case)
   df.sample = lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(df) {
     df[sample(1:nrow(df), ceiling(nrow(df) * 0.1)), ]
   })
   ```

   This gives us a `list` containing three data frames, one for each of the three different unique values of `Species`.
3. Combine the three samples into a single data frame.

   ```
   df.sample = do.call(rbind, df.sample)
   ```

#### dplyr package

Do the grouping and sampling in a single chain of functions using the pipe (`%>%`) operator:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample 5 values from each stratum
df.sample = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  sample_n(5)

# Sample a percentage of values from each stratum (10% in this case)
df.sample = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  sample_frac(0.1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @eipi10! The code I used, could you check: DB.quant.sample = lapply(split(DB.quant, DB.quant$group_size), function(DB.quant) {
  DB.quant[sample(1:nrow(DB.quant), ceiling(nrow(DB.quant) * 0.1)), ]
}) DB.quant is the data set and DB.quant$group_size is one of the variable. Which variable should I use? My end goal of it all is to do cluster and now after using  d <- dist(DB.quant.sample, method = "euclidean") I get - 
Error in dist(DB.quant.sample, method = "euclidean") : 
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.Do you know what is the problem, did i do sampling wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code to your question. It's very hard to read in a comment.

Comment: I just added it for you. Hope I made myself clearer, thanks a lot for your help